# How to get new updated text taken from user at up and old text below new one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is by using following code i get new updated status/text one below another i.e. new recently updated status displays after the old status again if i updated it goes below and so on...

I need that when user enter any status it should be displayed at up side than previous status it means new recently updated status should display on up side and old status below and so on...
PLEASE HELP...

I am using following code to display status in javascript

```
var btn = document.getElementById('statbtn');
    var stat = document.getElementById("status");
    var bigBox = document.getElementById("bigbox")


    function update() {
        var status = stat.value;
        bigBox.innerHTML += "<div id='box1'>"+ status + "</div>";
        stat.value = '';
        btn.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    }


    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        btn.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    });


    stat.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
        var btn = document.getElementById('statbtn');
        if(this.value){
            btn.removeAttribute('disabled','');
        } else {
            btn.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });
```

and my html code is

```
<div id='box'>
                 <h4>Update Your Customers</h4>
                 <form id="stat">
                     <textarea type="text" name="status" id="status" placeholder="Anything You Want To Say...?"></textarea>
                 </form>     
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id='statbtn' type="submit" onclick="update()">Update</button>
             </div>
<div id="bigbox">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are flexible with using jQuery, this should work:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('statbtn'),
    stat = document.getElementById("status");

function update() {
  var status = stat.value;
  $("#bigbox").prepend("<div>" + status + "</div>");
  stat.value = '';
  btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
});

stat.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('statbtn');
  if (this.value) {
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled', '');
  } else {
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i was searching all over internet for that one line Thank you so much...

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert it before the first child of `bigBox`

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('statbtn');
var stat = document.getElementById("status");
var bigBox = document.getElementById("bigbox")

function update() {
  var status = stat.value;
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); //Create new div
  newDiv.innerHTML = status; //Put the status insie new div
  bigBox.insertBefore(newDiv, bigBox.firstChild); //Insert the new div before the first child of BigBox
  stat.value = ''; //reset textarea
  btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); //disable button
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
});

stat.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('statbtn');
  if (this.value) {
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled', '');
  } else {
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<div id='box'>
  <h4>Update Your Customers</h4>
  <form id="stat">
    <textarea type="text" name="status" id="status" placeholder="Anything You Want To Say...?"></textarea>
  </form>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id='statbtn' type="submit" onclick="update()">Update</button>
</div>
<div id="bigbox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change "bigBox.innerHTML +=" to "= xxxx + bigBox.innerHTML";

```
function update() {
    var status = stat.value;
    bigBox.innerHTML = "<div id='box1'>"+ status + "</div>" + bigBox.innerHTML;
    stat.value = '';
    btn.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
}
```